# Stop file access from Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a server application that allows users to execute their own ruby scripts. The server that the scripts run on is a virtual instance on Amazon's EC2 so no permanent damage can be done. However I'd like to take whatever precautions I can to stop any dangerous/malicious script, reboots are still something I'd like to avoid.

At the moment I disallow any scripts that contain "require" or "include". I think it would actualy be safe to allow "include"? There is no need for any users to access the server's file system so if I disallow any occurrence of the string "file." will that prevent users being able to access the server's file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disallowing occurrence of the string "file" will not help you at all.  They still have eval, pack/unpack, Dir, ` and tons of other stuff.

YMMV, but this is what I would have done:

- Run the ruby process as an unprivileged user
- in a jailed environment (i.e. chroot, freebsd jail or equivalent)
- in a stripped environment (no suids, no other unnecessary files -- bare minimum is best)
- with [$SAFE](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/taint.html) >= 2
- and with no write access to any files/folders

Probably still not secure, but it's a start.

EDIT: Might also be a good idea to set limits on system resource consumption using ulimit or equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are in for a guessing game. Wouldn't it be easier to run the scripts as a user with very low privileges? <strike>Or you could take a look at how [TryRuby](http://github.com/Sophrinix/TryRuby) solved similar problems.</strike>

Seems there are several options for [sandboxing Ruby](http://flouri.sh/2009/4/11/ruby-sandboxing-resources) but I haven't used [any](http://flouri.sh/2009/4/4/how-to-set-up-the-ruby-sandbox) of them so I can't hand out [recommendations](http://pivotallabs.com/users/chad/blog/articles/781-playing-with-fire-running-uploaded-ruby-code-in-a-sandbox-david-stevenson).